# Assign inner class function variable to class variable

Tags: angular, function, websocket

I the following class leveled variable

```
protected _sliderValue: number = 50;
```

In my `ngOnInit` I am connecting to a websocket server. The connection gets established and I am receiving messages from the server which I can log to the console.

```
const connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9999/webSocket');
connection.onmessage = function (e){
  console.log('Server: ' + e.data);
};
```

My question is now ho can I assign the class variable `_sliderValue` to the received `e.data` in the `onmessage` event of the websocket connection? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to scope being an issue , use the typescript arrow function to maintain the correct scope or instance of 'this'

```
connection.onmessage =(e)=>{
  console.log('Server: ' + e.data);
  this._sliderValue = e.data;
};
```

More information can be found here
https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

**First (old school): declare that**

```
const connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9999/webSocket');

let that = this;
connection.onmessage = function (e){
console.log('Server: ' + e.data);
  that._sliderValue = e.data;
};
```

This works because `that` is a reference to `this` and stays accessible inside the function, although `this` is something else.

**Second (modern): Use arrow functions**

```
const connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9999/webSocket');
connection.onmessage = (e) => {
  console.log('Server: ' + e.data);
  that._sliderValue = e.data;
};
```

Arrow functions don't create their own scope but instead, use the same as their parent. Therefore you'll still be able to access `this`. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for more information.